# reading particular text from file with awk

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sed, awk

I need to read some values from a file with awk and then need to use the values that I read in bash.For example the structure of file will be

```
NICE = -13

LATENCY= 100

WMEM= 4
```

I need to read the values -13, 100 and 4 from the file with awk and then use them in bash. The structure of script will be;

```
#!/bin/bash

awk'{}'
```

and then use the values here in script

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/) Do you konw [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) [questions the smart way](http://catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your input is in `data.txt` then try running the following command inside your script:

```
values=`cat data.txt | awk -F '=' '{print $2}' | xargs`
```

values variable will then contain: -13 100 4

Comment: thanks @pankar, what if it will be if I need only one of these for example NICE? will it be `cat data.txt | awk -F 'NICE=' '{print $2}' | xargs` ?

Comment: @barp if u want "NICE" den use...... >values=`cat kk | grep "NICE" | awk -F '=' '{print $2}' | xargs`

Comment: What's the`xargs` for? Newline-separated values should be no harder to handle.

Answer (score 3):

```
values=($(awk 'NF{print $NF}' file))
```

This will create an array in bash.
The array contains all last token of non-empty lines.
You can access the values in the array with

```
echo ${values[0]}
```

to echo the first values.
Be aware there mustn't be spaces around the `=`

In the awk-Code the first `NF` filters out empty lines.
You can leave it off, if your file does not contain empty lines.